# Code-formatting in VS2017 for TypeScript files

Tags: typescript, formatting, visual-studio-2017, code-formatting

I want to format my TypeScript Code with Ctrl+K+D. Unfortunately nothing happens. With all other code files it works like expected. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, along with intellisense missing and other formatting issues.  I went to:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript/TypeScript -> Intellisense

There I had to tell it which version of TypeScript I was using; it was blank before I selected my version.